# Remove author from title page keep in footer on Beamer

Tags: beamer

I was wondering since I'm new to Beamer, if there was a way to prevent `\author{}` from showing up on the title page, I would however, like to keep it in the footer of my slides.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. In the very least, provide your preamble the shows the construction of the title components and creation, as well as how this ends up in the footer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the optional argument of `\author` for setting the "short" author version, while leaving the mandatory argument empty:

```
\author[Name]{}
```

Commonly, the optional argument of `\author` will be used in the footer, the mandatory argument on the title page, for example with `Copenhagen`, `Madrid`, `Berlin`, `Boadilla` and furher themes.